# Starting Kafka Connect Debezium

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I have confluent platform set up here

STEP 1

```
wget /usr/local http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.2/confluent-5.2.0-2.11.tar.gz -P ~/Downloads/
tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/confluent-5.2.0-2.11.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/
sudo mv ~/Downloads/confluent-5.2.0 /usr/local/confluent
```

STEP 2

I have also downloaded debizium my sql jar

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql/0.9.2.Final/debezium-connector-mysql-0.9.2.Final-plugin.tar.gz
```

STEP 3

I kept this jar inside `/usr/local/confluent/share/java/debezium`

STEP 4

I Modified `/usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties`
with `plugin.path=/usr/local/confluent/share/java,/usr/local/confluent/share/java/debezium`

Now where i can modify source related properties ?
How do i start my connector?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest installing Confluent via APT or YUM, not tarballs. Then you can upgrade and install components easier. For example, [Confluent Hub allows you to install Debezium](https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql).

`/usr/local/confluent/bin` includes two scripts to run Kafka Connect.

Maybe it'd help by referring to the documentation on [Running and Configuring Connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html) but your source related properties need to be created in your own properties file, using the [mysql Debezium options](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/mysql.html)

---

I would also recommend getting the latest Debezium release